# AngularJS (1.1.5): Can you cancel Directives with priority cancel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to keep the built-in ng-click handler from firing when you have a custom ng-click directive with a priority > 0 that fires first?  Or to delay the built-in one in some way?

In my case I have a custom ngClick directive that applies an animation to an element then waits for the animation to complete.  Once it is complete, and only then, should the built-in ngClick fire.  Reasoning is that the clicked element is on a slide-out drawer that is automatically hidden from within the ngClick handler. If the directive can't keep it from firing, then the drawer is closed before the animation even starts.

From the custom directive, I can use this to invoke the default ngClick, but the original needs to be cancelled in this case...

**Requirement: The solution should not require the developer write any code within their ngClick handler.**  I am definitely able to code this in the controller, but want to avoid having the controller having to know that it is supposed to wait.  (i.e. in case I change how the directive implements the indicator and it takes a different amount of time)

```
$timeout(function() {service.close();}, 400);
```

Here is an example of what I want to accomplish.

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="product in service.products"
    ng-click="onClick('{{product}}')"
    pre-click="onClicking('{{product}}')"
    animate="wasClicked(product)">
    {{product}}
</li>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('sales.directives')
    .directive('ngClick', [
        '$timeout',
        function ($timeout) {
            return {
                priority: 50,  // higher priority
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: false,
                link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                    element.bind('click', function () {
                        if (attributes.preClick) {
                            eval('scope.' + attributes.preClick);
                        }
                    });

                    if (attributes.animate !== undefined) {
                        scope.$watch(attributes.animate, function (newValue) {
                            if (newValue == true) {
                                element.addClass('animated');
                                // pause 400ms so animation can complete
                                $timeout(angular.noop, 400)
                                    .then(function () {
                                        element.removeClass('animated');
                                        // I would like to invoke the original 
                                        // ngClick here, and then remove it from the 
                                        // queue so that it doesn't fire it again.
                                        // Reason for invoking it here is that if I
                                        // don't, then the base ngClick event will
                                        // fire before this promise is resolved.
                                        eval('scope.' + element.ngClick);
                                        // ??
                                    });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
        }]);
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('sales')
    .controller(
        'ProductController',
        [
            '$scope', 'ProductService',
            function ($scope, $timeout, service) {

                $scope.clickedProduct = null;

                $scope.onClicking = function (product) {
                    $scope.clickedProduct = product;
                };

                $scope.wasClicked = function (product) {
                    return $scope.clickedProduct === product;
                };

                $scope.onClick = function (product) {
                    service.selected = product;
                };
            }
        ]);
```

Any thoughts?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I suggest you to do `scope.$eval(attributes.preClick)` instead of the evil browser `eval()`...

Comment: I agree @gustavohenke. Just hacked this together for illustration purposes. Now, how to cancel the real click. Can stop propogation come into play somehow I wonder?

Comment: Nope, stopPropogation and preventDefault do not work. Hmm.

Comment: Any luck solving this? Did you find another way to approach things?